# Cinnamon Menu Search shows non-existent .desktop files

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, menu

when I open the Cinnamon main Menu and search for *someTool* I get a couple of files that don't exist:

```
/home/username/someTool.desktop
/home/username/Shortcuts/someTool.desktop
/usr/share/applications/someTool.desktop
```

How can I remove them from the search menu index?

I already rebooted the OS.
And of cause I have deleted all files and emptied the trash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-existent files are no more shown. I didn't do anything particular. Time just passed. I guess there is a cron-task or somthing that updates the list once in a while. Problem solved.